# What compiler flags should be used to obtain IEEE 754 compatible float on Arm architecture?

Tags: gcc, floating-point, arm, ieee-754

I'm a little bit confused with the ARM GCC documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

Which flags shall I use to build a program for ARM Cortex A7 so that single precision floating point numbers follow IEEE 754 standard?

I know that if I use `-mfpu=neon` then I lose IEEE 754 compatibility, what if I don't use it at all? I don't care about a bit slower calculations.

Thanks in advance!

BR
zdun8

Comment: AARCH32 Neon isn't IEEE754 compliant regardless of the compiler option. `VFP` on the other hand is fully compliant UNLESS you set the `fast-math` option. Leave the `-mfpu=neon` and just don't use neon. NEON ALWAYS comes with VFP.

Comment: Do you mean that I should remove `-mfpu=neon` flag and then by deafult it will use VFP which is IEEE754 compliant?

Comment: No, leave it there as it is. neon includes VFP.

Comment: Okay, this is a bit confusing as I though that if I set the `-mfpu=neon` option it will use neon which is not IEEE754 compliant.

Comment: Perhaps `--fpmode=ieee_full` could also be added to make sure.

Comment: the note in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html#index-mfpu-1 is consistant with @Jake'Alquimista'LEE says, just don't enable auto-vectorisation and it should do what you want.  you could maybe also use https://godbolt.org/ to verify that it's using the appropriate machine code